# How to wrap all functions imported from a module?

Tags: python

Is it possible to apply code from imported module to module which import it?
For example, I have module Debug where defined some decorator for debugging, for example:

```
def debug_func(f):
    def wrapper(*func_args, **func_kwargs):
        print(f(*func_args, **func_kwargs))
    return wrapper
```

What's the idea: It's would be useful if I can just

```
import Debug
```

and all functions from current module will wrapped with decorator.
Is it possible?

Comment: You'd need to call a function in `Debug` after importing; `Debug` probably can't reflect on the importing module while it itself is being imported. IMHO, you're better off doing `from Debug import debug_func` and then using the `@debug_func` decorator on those functions that need it. It wouldn't be too hard to write a regexp that could comment or uncomment all instances of `@debug_func` in a file.

Comment: I guess you could write a `decorate_all` function, that takes a function as parameter, looks at all the `callable` entries in `gobals()` and decorates them, or something similar. Call this after the import.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within Debug.py:

```
import functools
from types import FunctionType

def wrap_functions(module_dict):
    for k, f in module_dict.items():
        if not isinstance(f, FunctionType):
            continue
        def get_wrapper(f):
            def wrapper(*func_args, **func_kwargs):
                print(f(*func_args, **func_kwargs))
            return functools.wraps(f)(wrapper)
        module_dict[k] = get_wrapper(f)
```

At the *bottom* of the module you are wishing to debug:

```
import Debug
Debug.wrap_functions(globals())
```

Thanks (+1) to all the commenters who provided suggestions.

Comment: You've got it backwards. He wants `import Debug` to wrap the importing module's functions, not Debug's functions.

Comment: Instead of copying the decorator in the function, why don't you pass the decorator(s) to use as another parameter? Also, better use `Debug.wrap_functions(globals())`, otherwise `wrap_function` will decorate itself. Apart from that, +1

Comment: I read your original answer, then went away to do some checking and came back to find what I had been planning on writing :).

Comment: @AndrewAylett Same for me, see my comment under the question. :-)

Answer (score 3):

How would `Debug` know what module it's being imported from? Answer: It can't. How would `Debug` know to run more than once if it's imported into more than one module? Answer: It wouldn't; modules are only run once and then cached. So what you want to do can't be done quite as simply as you want to.

You could, however, do it by calling a function in your `debug` module after importing. You can pass `__name__` from the calling module to provide its name, after which it's possible to get a reference to the module itself, and then the top-level variables defined in it, some of which may be functions. These may then be decorated.

```
# debug.py
import types, sys, functools

# decorator to be applied to all top-level functions in a module
def debug(fn):
    @functools.wraps(fn)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print "calling", fn.__name__, "with args", *args, **kwargs
        result = fn(*args, **kwargs)
        print "returning from", fn.__name__, "with return value", result
        return result

# decorate all top-level functions in named module with a given decorator
# (by default it is the above decorator but it could be a different one)
# This makes these functions behave as though they had been written with
# @debug above them.
def set_debug(modname, debug=debug):
    module = sys.modules[modname]
    for name in dir(module):
        if not name.startswith("_"):
            thing = getattr(module, name)
            if isinstance(thing, types.FunctionType):
                setattr(module, name, debug(thing))
```

Now in the calling module:

```
# main.py
import debug

def main():
    print "in main module"

debug.set_debug(__name__)   # install debugging decorator

main()
```

Jim Garrison's approach of passing the namespace explicitly (rather than the module name) is also good and actually simplifies things a bit; you could use it to decorate things other than modules. I've broken mine up so you can pass in a different decorator if you want.

Answer (score 0):

I think the pythonic way of doing it would be to have your Debug call the debugged module, as the standard tools (`pdb`, `unittest`, ...) with a call like:

```
$ python -m Debug mymodule.py
```

With your Debug importing/executing the module with any decorators you like. Doing it the other way (importing `Debug`) messes with the order in which modules are evaluated, as you are trying to have your `Debug` module depend on the module importing it, which is tricky at best.

Apart from passing your functions explicitly (via `globals()`, a list of functions...) to some `Debug.mark_as_debug` as Jim Garrison suggested, I think it would make more sense to organise your code such that you can have your `Debug` call your modules instead of the other way around.

Comment: Thanks, but I wrote debug as example, primary issue - what is the best way to apply code from imported module to module which import it.

Comment: I think the answer to this question is: you can't. kindall explains it much better than I did, but the very principle of modules goes against it (although you can add hooks to be called from the importing module as he and Jim Garrison showed). I don't think there is any (proper) way of having a module knowing its caller and modifying it without any callback

Comment: Well, technically I think you could do it with an import hook, but that seems *very* dirty.